# Bad credentials symfony

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am moving my application to symfony and i can't get the login to work. I always get a "Bad credentials" error.

The passwords in my database where previously hashed using this : `password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,array('cost'=>10));`.

I think i have setup encoder in the security.yml correctly :

```
encoders:
    UserBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 10
        iterations: 1
        encode_as_base64: false
```

Any idea how to solve this ? Thanks !!

Comment: What about `encode_as_base64: false`? Are you sure you want that?

Comment: Could it be a problem with the salt ?

Comment: The passwords were not base64 encoded before so it thing its ok (i tried to set it to true but still not working). And for the salt, i think it is not needed for bcrypt so i have set the getSalt() method to return null in my user entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally found the answer to my question. I have set the iterations to zero and it worked. Don't really understand why but it worked :) Thanks for your help !